# When I fork a process in Perl, can the child process see its parent's data

Tags: perl, fork

Say I am building a webcrawler and I have a hash that contains all the visited URLs.

When I fork child processes I would like to be able to access the hash of visited URLs from the child process but I don't want to copy the hash since it's big and it will drain the computer's memory.

When I fork using Parallel::ForkManager and I print the address of a hash that was declared in the parent process I get the same address when I print from the parent and from the child e.g HASH(0x7fc59d017f38)

But I want to make sure the data structure isn't being copied to the child process

Comment: Are you using green threads or native threads? `perl -v` will help.

Comment: On U*x (including OSX) the child has no access to the parent. However, it inherits a complete copy of the parent's memory (which is typically optimized to be copy-on-write). On other platforms, some details may differ.

Comment: The child has access to a snapshot of the parent data taken at the moment of the fork.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer darwin-thread-multi-2level

Comment: Could you just have the child process pass its URLs (without saving them) to the parent process for storage once the child has processed them, or does the child need them for future reference? If the child doesn't need to keep them around, you could fork using IO::Pipe::Producer to pass the URLs to the parent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Each process has its own address space. The child's address space starts as a copy of its parent's, but changing either will have no effect on the other. You'll need to explicitly exchange the data you want to "share" by using one of a variety of possible communication channel (pipes, memcached, database, file, etc).

Comment: Thanks, but why does it say they have the same address when I print the hash

Comment: `say \%hash;
if(fork == 0){
 say \%hash
}`

Comment: Yes, the same address in two different address spaces. Kinda like two people having the same street address in two different cities. It doesn't mean they share a bathroom. Memory addresses don't refer to a location on a memory chip, but a location in the process's address space.

Comment: `$hash{abc} = 123; if(my $pid = fork) { waitpid($pid, 0); say $hash{abc} }  else { $hash{abc} = 456; }`

Comment: Actually I think this answer is wrong, because the question was "can the child see its parent's data?". The answer is that the child *can* see the parent's data at the time of fork, but the child cannot update the parent's data, and updates made by the parent after the fork are not visible by the child. So the answer should be "Yes", not "No".

Comment: @U. Windl, If you're going to answer the literal question, it's actually "*I want to make sure the data structure isn't being copied to the child process*". The answer to that is "no, until it's yes". The child shares the parent's memory page until something in the memory page changes, which will cause a copy. One can't predict when that will happen since even just reading a scalar (e.g. printing it) can cause it to change. I'll try to update the answer in a bit.

Comment: @ikegami It all depends on the details that aren't presented, but huge data structures are not "copied" (what the OP wanted to avoid obviously), but "shared" (i.e. some page table entries are copied (more or less)). The question whether, how long, and to what extent those pages remain shared pages: That is impossible to answer with the information given. Garbage collection can ruin the game, too.

Comment: @U. Windl, Re "*but huge data structures are not "copied"*". As I explained above, that's not usually true. Since merely looking at the data structure can cause it to be modified and thus copied, there's a really good chance it is. For example, this causes the data structure to be copied if the values are references: `for my $key ( keys( %hash ) ) { my $val = $hash{ $key }; ... }`

Comment: @U. Windl Re "*Garbage collection can ruin the game, too.*", yup! If the structure didn't end up being copied before the child exist, it will get copied then as the reference counts get decreased.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parent's hash from the child process, but you cannot update the parent's hash, just as the child cannot see any of the parent's updates after the fork was done.

That is because both processes use the same virtual address space, but have a separate physical address space mapping that is shared as "copy on write" initially (at least on almost any current operating system).
That means those shared data are in RAM (if at all) only once, but as soon as any of the parent of children do modify the data, a copy of the modified page is made.